# Extract number from string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, substring, charindex

I have a table with a column that is including different remarks of an specific process.

Sometimes there is 1 remark, and sometimes 4 different remarks.

It looks something like this :

```
Remarks 
|180|
|180|
|180|
|180|360|
|180|
|180|
|180|
|180|360|
```

I need to have the remarks in different columns.

I'm looking specific in a few remarks so I can create a case per each column.

Could you advice how to extract or looked for the number into the tuple ?

Comment: So are you storing delimited data in your column? That's the real problem, fix your design, fix the problem. It shouldn't be 1 column with delimited data, nor 4 columns; it should (likely) be 2 columns; a Remark Number and a Remark Value.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: ^ especially #4

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2016 and up:

```
;WITH shattered AS 
(
  SELECT t.Remarks, j.[key], j.value
    FROM dbo.TheTable AS t
    CROSS APPLY 
      OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(t.Remarks, '|', '","') + '"]') AS j
    WHERE j.value > ''
)
SELECT Remarks, 
       Remark1 = [1], 
       Remark2 = [2], 
       Remark3 = [3], 
       Remark4 = [4]
FROM shattered 
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR [key] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) AS p;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a0b3d6cce105dc0f82a8275d173a391a)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `STRING_SPLIT` and `PIVOT` on modern versions of SQL Server

```
SELECT
  Remarks.*
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT
          s.value,
          rn = CONCAT('Remarks', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)))
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(t.Remarks, '|') s
        WHERE s.value <> ''
    ) s
    PIVOT (
        MAX(value) FOR (rn IN
            (Remarks1, Remarks2, Remarks3, Remarks4)
    ) p
) Remarks;
```

Comment: Well, `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` does not guarantee order. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql): `The output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string.` Maybe order isn't important to the OP, and maybe it never fails in practice; but it might be, and it could.

Comment: Firstly, no mention of that in OP. Secondly, what happened re Microsoft confirming to you that they were guaranteeing it. We argued about it a while back, I simply didn't see how it is even possible for it to result in anything else. The `ROW_NUMBER` is calculated at the lowest level, before the `PIVOT`, and there is no reason for the compiler to reorder the results (`STRING_SPLIT` itself is always serial, as is `ROW_NUMBER`, so you can't have a parallel zone between them)

Comment: _Someone_ at Microsoft said they believed that's how it works. _Someone else_ at Microsoft said it is not guaranteed and to scrub any suggestion that it was. The point is, it's not guaranteed, and anyone who uses the code should be made aware of that.